# Maximum and minimum value of probability

Tags: probability

My teacher doesn't give answers to exercises. I am not sure about 4th question. Could you tell me please if it is right or not?

Let A and B be two events, with P(A ∩ B) = 0.2 and the probability of B, P(B), = 0.7.

**a.    What is P(A|B)?**

0.2/0.7 = 0.3

**b.    What is P(A) if the two events are independent?**

P(A|B) = P(A) = 0.3

**c.    Can events A and B be exhaustive?**

Yes, because: P(A) + P(B) = S = 1
P(A) + 0.7 = 1.

if P(A) = 0.3 then events A and B are exhaustive.

**d.    What are the minimum and maximum value of P(A)?**

Max.value of P(A) is 0.3

Min. value of P(A) is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For d) the maximum value is $0.5$ and the minimum is $0.2$. For an example where $P(A)=0.5$ partition the probability space into three parts $C,D,E$ with $P(C)=0.3, P(D)=0.2$ and $P(E)=0.5$. Take $A=C\cup D$ and $B=D\cup E$.
For the mimimum consider an example with $A \subset B$.

Answer (score 0):

a), b)  are correct; just a minor observation:

a) and b) are $\frac{2}{7}$, not exactly 0.3

c) the right answer is $P(A)=0.5$

d) max value of $P(A)=0.5$ and its min value is obviously $0.2=P(A\cap B)$

These diagrams show the two limit situations, Max and Min value for $P(A)$

[image]

B is indicated as the blue event and A with the red one